# ES6 & Webpack - imported factory functions not working

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I am learning webpack and trying to utilise it for my current project. I have followed the Getting Started guide on their website.

I have the following files:

**project.js**

```
const Project = (projectName, dueDate = null, pri = "normal") => {

const name = projectName;
const created = new Date();
const due = dueDate;
const completed = 0; //0 == uncompleted, 1 == completed
const priority = pri


return {
    name,
    created,
    due,
    completed,
    priority,
    }
}

export { Project };
```

**index.js**

```
import { Project } from './projects';
console.log(Project)
```

In my browser console, on page load, the Project FF is logged correctly as so:

```
(projectName, dueDate = null, pri = "normal") => {

const name = projectName;
const created = new Date();
const due = dueDate;
const completed = 0; //0 == uncompleted, 1 == completed
```

However when I attempt a simple command like:

```
let x = Project("test project")
```

I receive the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Project is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:9
```

I think this must be something to do with my webpack config, which looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
```

module.exports = {

```
   mode: 'development', 
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },  
};
```

But I am scratching my head, unable to work out what the issue is. The code all seems fine, but the linking of it does not.

Comment: @abhay that makes no difference unfortunately

Comment: @evolutionxbox sadly I don't think this is the issue. Changing the export just throws an error. The fact that the object *is* being console logged within index.js suggests it should be importing?

Comment: You're right, that isn't the issue. May you create a codesandbox, or similar, to go along with this question? That way you can show us a [mcve]?

Comment: @evolutionxbox could it be something to do with webpack renaming my functions when they are bundled together?

Comment: It could be? May you try making codesandbox example?

Comment: @evolutionxbox here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-rgb-lnuv4?file=/index.html

I'm not sure whether it will be helpful as webpack is not initiated on this codesandbox. The code works fine in the scripts I've written but doesn't work when I try to enter it in the console, leading me to believe that it's because webpack is changing the names of my functions?

Comment: Is `let x = Project("test project")` inside a script in the project, or are you running it somewhere else?